# Meu código php não deixa ele fazer login, (penso que seja devido ao metodo $_POST)

Tags: php, html

Boa noite, Estou fazendo um código em php para confirmar se o usuario existe na base de dados para entrar noutra pagina Home, para isso retiro os dados pelo método $_POST do formulário, mas pelo que vi o POST não funcionava, então tentei de outras formas mas continua sem efeito, vou deixar em baixo como ficou.

Login.php [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Index.php [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

db.php [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo, sempre que executo o login com os dados existentes na base de dados, ele me retorna ao index, alguem me puderia ajudar?

Comment: Não poste códigos como imagem, a plataforma tem suporte a códigos diretamente na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Opa, pelo que parece, no seu arquivo 'Login.php' na linha 8, vc está fazendo uma validação `isset($_POST['submit'])`, e essa condição vai ser sempre verdadeira, pois seu formulário sempre vai enviar esse campo com o `name=value` que você atribuiu.

Logo, o código está vendo que existe esse valor no array `$_POST` e entrando no if, encaminhando o acesso para seu `index.php`, como definido =)

Essa condição não faz muito sentido, acredito que ela é para verificar se existe o método post na página, então o correto para isso seria `if( !isset($_POST['sumbmit'] )`, daí encaminhar de volta pro index.

Espero ter ajudado!!

Comment: Eu não conheço muito bem php, eu trabalho mais com C#, mas foi me pedido que fizesse em formato WEB, e como eu não conheço bem php estou tendo algumas dúvidas, porém eu alterei o que referiu e continua reencaminhando para o index.php, Eu tentei continuar o restante de forma a ver se conseguiria alguma ajuda nessa parte, porém na parte do resgisto ela funciona excelentemente, mas ao tentar adicionar dados através de campos separados ela não funciona também. Vou deixar em baixo o meu email e se me puder ajudar mais eu agradecia pois o tempo é pouco para o que necessito, agradeceriam imenso

Comment: Esqueci de enviar o email 3642.tomas.luis@eped.pt